# Could I create "Call" button in HTML 5 IPhone application using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

Could I create "Call" button in HTML 5 IPhone application using PhoneGap? Pushing this button should invoke call to certain number on IPhone device.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can specify a URL for the button, use the URL format `tel:phonenumber`.

Comment: This link doesn't work in Iphone emulator:<a href="tel:+1-800-275-2273">
Call Apple Customer Support at 1-800-275-2273
</a>

Comment: Is there some standard behind this? Is this from the HTML5 spec?

Comment: @MikeMurko - its been that way since wap.

Comment: OK, I just thought it would be interesting to get more details on it (i.e. what formats are acceptable). I just tested this on Gingerbread Android and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: make sure there are no ```event.preventDefault()``` on that link because following the link with something like ```window.location = href``` doesn't do the trick on some devices like the iphone 6+.

Comment: I was using extra // with tel, window.location.href="tel://"+phonenumber; Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 7):

Best format is no punctuation in the number, so:

```
<a href="tel:+18002752273"> Call Apple Customer Support at 1-800-275-2273 </a>
```

Comment: Nick's link above works well, thanks!  Is it possible to circumvent the [Cancel | Call] alert box and have the call go through directly without having to accept the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Use this "tel:phonenumber"
it will NOT work on emulator, but it works on real device.