# Hyperlink to call a number from an HTML5 app for iOS

Tags: ios, html, hyperlink, 3cx

How to add a hyperlink in an HTML5 application, so I can call a specific number with 3cx application for iPhone?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164642/could-i-create-call-button-in-html-5-iphone-application-using-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
<a href="tel:+18001111111"> Phone Call </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually html link is same for all calls, how You call to it is depends on phone settings.